# How to store values from an SQL query into a ComboBox component?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-6, tcombobox

I have a problem with the `TComboBox` component in Borland C++Builder 6.

In the ComboBox, I want to insert the result of an SQL query, eg:

```
ID  value
---------
1   one
2   two
3   three
```

I want to display the values of the `value` column to the user, e.g. `one`, `two`, `three`, but reference the values of the `ID` column.

Can anyone help me? Google did not say a lot about this to me.

Comment: The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. 


Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

apologize forgot to put in some code

```
ComboBox1->AddItem("one", (TObject *) 1);
ComboBox1->AddItem("two", (TObject *) 2);
ComboBox1->AddItem("three", (TObject *) 3);
```

in my combobox the values one, two, three are displayed correctly
now I would like to display the id of the currently selected item, e.g. 2

```
Label1->Caption = ???
```

and I do not know how to reference the ID values

Comment: FYI, this belonged as an edit to your original question, not posted as an answer. But in any case, to answer your second question, use the [`Items->Objects[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Objects) property, eg: `Label1->Caption = (int)(ComboBox1->Items->Objects[ComboBox1->ItemIndex]);`

Answer (score 0):

someone answered me on another forum but I would like to share this solution with you

I'm filling out the combobox component

```
cbx1->Items->Clear();
cbx1->AddItem("one",(TObject*)1);
cbx1->AddItem("two",(TObject*)2);
cbx1->AddItem("three",(TObject*)3);
cbx1->ItemIndex = 0;
```

read the ID of the selected item

```
int ID;
ID = (int)(cbx1->Items->Objects[cbx1->ItemIndex]);
ShowMessage(ID);
```

Comment: 2 hours after I posted the *exact* same solution as a comment to your earlier answer here ;-)