# C++Builder - cannot cast from 'AnsiString' to 'TObject'

Tags: type-conversion, c++builder, c++builder-6, tdataset, tcombobox

I have a problem with converting a string variable to `TObject`.

I have a query that returns two columns to me. In the first column I have `varchar` values that I translate into strings, and in the second column I have `int` values.

I want to fill a ComboBox in this way with these values:

```
cbx1-> AddItem (DataSet1->DataSet->Fields->Field[0]->AsString, (TObject *) (int) DataSet1->DataSet->Fields->Field[1];
```

As I refer to the second value which is int type, I receive some bushes, e.g., xD, etc.

By trying to convert this value to string, eg:

```
String temp = IntToStr (DataSet1->DataSet->Fields->Field[1]);
cbx1-> AddItem (DataSet1->DataSet->Fields->Field[0]->AsString, (TObject *) temp;
```

I receive an error message:

> cannot cast from 'AnsiString' to 'TObject'

I do not know what further I can do to convert this value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast an `AnsiString` **value** to a `TObject*` pointer.  You can only cast an integer value, or a pointer value, to a `TObject*` pointer.  `AnsiString` is neither of those.

You are not retrieving the `int` **value** from the 2nd field correctly anyway.  `Field[1]` is a pointer to an actual `TField` object in the `Fields` collection.  That pointer is what you are trying to store in your ComboBox, **NOT** the `int` **value** that the `TField` represents.

You need to call `Fields[1]->AsInteger` to get the `int` value of the 2nd field, similar to how you use `Fields[0]->AsString` to get the string value of the 1st field:

```cpp
cbx1->AddItem(
    DataSet1->DataSet->Fields->Field[0]->AsString,
    (TObject*) DataSet1->DataSet->Fields->Field[1]->AsInteger
    // in C++, using reinterpret_cast is preferred over C-style casting:
    // reinterpret_cast<TObject*>(DataSet1->DataSet->Fields->Field[1]->AsInteger)
);
```

This is no different than the code in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134551/):

```
cbx1->AddItem("one",(TObject*)1);
```

You are now just placing the literals `"one"` and `1` with runtime variables of equivalent types.